# Do DES keys have to be random?

Tags: cryptography, random, des

In [stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) (namely the [OTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) ) . The pad which the plain text is Xored with has to be random to achieve [perfect secrecy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/crypt/v/perfect-secrecy) , or psudorandom to ensure [semantic security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security)

Dose this apply to DES or block ciphers in general ?

Dose the randomness of the DES key effects the security ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you are doing plain old single DES, it doesn't matter -- 56-bit DES keys can be easily brute forced.  The [EFF DES cracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker) could break a 56-bit DES key in under a day way back in 1999.

Generally, yes its best to have a totally random key for symmetric encryption (block ciphers) as there will be no shortcuts when brute-forcing the key.

In practice, using a key generated by a [key-derivation-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) that constructs a pseudo-random key from a strong user-chosen password may be perfectly strong, provided you use a strong password.  However, the entropy of your pseudo-random derived key really will rest in how complicated the password is.  If your password is found in a common list of passwords or has a low inherent complexity, a skilled attacker can quickly recover your key.

So if you want 100-bits of security, you should choose a password with about 100 bits of entropy -- e.g., 17 random characters from A-Z,a-z,0-9; or 15 random characters from all printable ASCII, or about 8 random words chosen a 5000 word dictionary.  And say with AES-128 with a 100-bit password this will weaken the security from 2<sup>128</sup> to 2<sup>100</sup>.

Answer (score 3):

*Randomness* really is: *what the attacker does not know*. Therefore, encryption keys are precisely a thing where a lot of randomness is needed.

We usually talk of *entropy* in the following model:

- The key is generated with a process which involves computations (code) and random inputs (harvested from physical elements).
- The attacker is supposed to have perfect knowledge of the computations, but not of the random inputs.
- The attacker will try to recover the keys by trying the possible keys in optimal order, beginning with the most probable.

We say that the key has *n* bits of entropy if the attacker will hit the right one after, on average, 2<sup>*n*-1</sup> tries. Note that an *n*-bit key, where all key bits are uniformly and independently random, achieves exactly *n* bits of entropy, which is the point of the notation.

**A consequence** is that you cannot have more than *n* bits of entropy in a key of *n* bits (so a DES key can *never* be stronger than 56 bits of entropy, which is too low for comfort as @drJimbob points out); but you can have much less. E.g., if the key generation process is about obtaining a random 32-bit integer, then hashing it with SHA-1 and keeping the first 56 bits of the output, then the entropy will be no more than 32 bits (an attacker could try all possible 32-bit values, hashing each of them: this will hit the right key with an average cost of at most 2<sup>31</sup>).

In general, you use symmetric encryption systems with *n*-bit keys (e.g. *n* = 128 for AES) and you want to get your money worth, i.e. *n*-bit entropy. This is the very reason why you use 128-bit keys: to make room for enough entropy to defeat all Earth-based attackers. Sometimes you accept to use less entropy because your source for the key is a piece of data which cannot be grown arbitrarily: in particular when keys are derived from *passwords*. Passwords fail to achieve high entropy because human minds are not good at remembering highly entropic passwords (and they are abysmally bad at *generating* random passwords).

When you process a data element through a deterministic key derivation function, you never increase the entropy, since, by definition of our attack model, the attacker could run the same deterministic key derivation function. You could, though, *lower* the entropy, if you do it carelessly. Cryptographically strong KDF don't lower the entropy below the limit implied by the key size (a 56-bit key can never contain more than 56 bits of entropy).